# Why the HTML meter bar not showing green and red color without the ‘optimum’ attribute on the <meter> element

Tags: html

As I was reading through the article on MDN called [Other form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Other_form_controls) and on the section [Progress and meter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Other_form_controls#meters_and_progress_bars) they explained the different attributes used with `<meter>` element.

With the `optimum` attribute everything works as expected like `<meter>` changes color from **green** to **yellow** and then **red** based on the different attribute values. Confusing arises when the `optimum` attribute is not present for example:

```
<meter id="fuel" min="0" max="100" low="33" high="66" value="25">25</meter>
```

According to the [`<meter>`: The HTML Meter element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter) page on **MDN** they says, the `low` attribute **Specifies the range that is considered to be a low value and it must be between min and max attribute values** which it is. So we should expect the color of this meter to be `red` because it is in the lower part of the range but it is `not red` it is **yellow** as the value which is **25** is between `min` and `low`.

Similarly, if we change the value to `75` which is higher than the `high` value it should be **red** but again it is **yellow**. I thought maybe without the `optimum` attribute it is behaving differently but then I found an example on the **MDN meter page** the example is:

```
He got a <meter low="69" high="80" max="100" value="84">B</meter> on the exam.
```

Here there is no `optimum` attribute present but the `<meter>` seems to work as expected the color is **red** but why is this working and the above example is not after digging into the example I found if we set the `low` value greater than **50** like **51** then it will work as expected I don’t know why this is happening maybe there is a default value for `optimum` attribute I don’t know that is where I hoping to get an explanation.

Without the `optimum` attribute expected the lower part of the range to be **green**, the medium part of the range to be **yellow**, and the higher part of the range to be **red** but this is not the case.

Thank you.